# Ionic 3 Bluetooth Permission not working for Android 12

Tags: android, node.js, typescript, cordova, ionic3

I'm experiencing problems in requesting the Bluetooth permission in my Ionic 3 app, version 3.20.0. It appears that the permission no longer appears as a pop-up to the user, and I require it to be requested. Here is the configuration of my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

also tried:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
             If your app doesn't use Bluetooth scan results to derive physical
             location information, you can strongly assert that your app
             doesn't derive physical location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
      devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
           devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!--bibo01 : hardware option-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
```

and I'm requesting the permission using the following code:

```
grantPermissions() {
    this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION]).then(result => {
if (result.hasPermission) {
          this.nextPage();
        }
      }
      )
      .catch(
        error => {
          if (error == "cordova_not_available") {
            this.nextPage();
          }
        });
 }
```

I'm unsure of the issue, but it seems to be related to the Android 12 version. Can someone confirm if it's completely incompatible or if there's a correct way to request it?

Ionic version: 3.20.0
Cordova version: 11.0.0
Node version: 10.16.0
Npm version: 6.14.12